# Why do printf implementators prefer to print "%a" numbers with a leading 1?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

Recently I wrote the following program to test printing different floating point types with the `%a` specifier:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ELEM(x)   { #x, x }
#define FLT_C(x)  ELEM(x##f)
#define DBL_C(x)  ELEM(x)
#define LDBL_C(x) ELEM(x##L)
#define TEST(TYPE, C, PRI) do { \
    /* some random numbers, do not matter really */ \
    const struct { const char *str; TYPE val; } nums[] = { \
        C(123.456), C(456.789), \
        C(123.678e10), C(678.890e-10), \
        C(1/0.3), C(0.5) \
    }; \
    /* foreach number in nums */ \
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(nums)/sizeof(*nums); ++i) { \
        printf("%15s %-20s = %"PRI"a\n", #TYPE, nums[i].str, nums[i].val); \
        /*                     ^^^^^^^ - print with %a with proper specifier */ \
    } \
} while(0)

int main() {
    printf("%38s\n", 
#if defined __GLIBC__
    "GLIBC"
#elif defined __NEWLIB__
    "NEWLIB"
#else
    "alpine"
#endif
    );
    TEST(float,       FLT_C,  "");
    TEST(double,      DBL_C, "l");
    TEST(long double, LDBL_C, "L");
}
```

I ran the program with different standard library implementations I had at hand ([Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/7x8j7f)):

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra /tmp/1.c && ./a.out && arm-none-eabi-gcc --specs=rdimon.specs -u_printf_float -u_scanf_float -specs=nosys.specs /tmp/1.c && qemu-arm /tmp/a.out && docker run -ti --rm -v /tmp/1.c:/tmp/1.c:ro alpine sh -c 'apk add build-base >/dev/null && gcc /tmp/1.c && ./a.out'
                                 GLIBC
          float 123.456f             = 0x1.edd2f2p+6
          float 456.789f             = 0x1.c8c9fcp+8
          float 123.678e10f          = 0x1.1ff5d6p+40
          float 678.890e-10f         = 0x1.2394bep-24
          float 1/0.3f               = 0x1.aaaaaap+1
          float 0.5f                 = 0x1p-1
         double 123.456              = 0x1.edd2f1a9fbe77p+6
         double 456.789              = 0x1.c8c9fbe76c8b4p+8
         double 123.678e10           = 0x1.1ff5d523p+40
         double 678.890e-10          = 0x1.2394beb1a4116p-24
         double 1/0.3                = 0x1.aaaaaaaaaaaabp+1
         double 0.5                  = 0x1p-1
    long double 123.456L             = 0xf.6e978d4fdf3b646p+3
    long double 456.789L             = 0xe.464fdf3b645a1cbp+5
    long double 123.678e10L          = 0x8.ffaea918p+37
    long double 678.890e-10L         = 0x9.1ca5f58d208ac05p-27
    long double 1/0.3L               = 0xd.555555555555555p-2
    long double 0.5L                 = 0x8p-4
                                NEWLIB
          float 123.456f             = 0x1.edd2f2p+6
          float 456.789f             = 0x1.c8c9fcp+8
          float 123.678e10f          = 0x1.1ff5d6p+40
          float 678.890e-10f         = 0x1.2394bep-24
          float 1/0.3f               = 0x1.aaaaaap+1
          float 0.5f                 = 0x1p-1
         double 123.456              = 0x1.edd2f1a9fbe77p+6
         double 456.789              = 0x1.c8c9fbe76c8b4p+8
         double 123.678e10           = 0x1.1ff5d523p+40
         double 678.890e-10          = 0x1.2394beb1a4116p-24
         double 1/0.3                = 0x1.aaaaaaaaaaaabp+1
         double 0.5                  = 0x1p-1
    long double 123.456L             = 0x1.edd2f1a9fbe77p+6
    long double 456.789L             = 0x1.c8c9fbe76c8b4p+8
    long double 123.678e10L          = 0x1.1ff5d523p+40
    long double 678.890e-10L         = 0x1.2394beb1a4116p-24
    long double 1/0.3L               = 0x1.aaaaaaaaaaaabp+1
    long double 0.5L                 = 0x1p-1
                                alpine
          float 123.456f             = 0x1.edd2f2p+6
          float 456.789f             = 0x1.c8c9fcp+8
          float 123.678e10f          = 0x1.1ff5d6p+40
          float 678.890e-10f         = 0x1.2394bep-24
          float 1/0.3f               = 0x1.aaaaaap+1
          float 0.5f                 = 0x1p-1
         double 123.456              = 0x1.edd2f1a9fbe77p+6
         double 456.789              = 0x1.c8c9fbe76c8b4p+8
         double 123.678e10           = 0x1.1ff5d523p+40
         double 678.890e-10          = 0x1.2394beb1a4116p-24
         double 1/0.3                = 0x1.aaaaaaaaaaaabp+1
         double 0.5                  = 0x1p-1
    long double 123.456L             = 0x1.edd2f1a9fbe76c8cp+6
    long double 456.789L             = 0x1.c8c9fbe76c8b4396p+8
    long double 123.678e10L          = 0x1.1ff5d523p+40
    long double 678.890e-10L         = 0x1.2394beb1a411580ap-24
    long double 1/0.3L               = 0x1.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaap+1
    long double 0.5L                 = 0x1p-1
```

I tested 3 implementations and all except glibc with `long double` print the hexadecimal floating point number with a leading `0x1`... Why `0x1`?

Is there a specific reason why 3 different implementations chose `0x1` as the initial part for printing a hexadecimal floating point number? Is it simplifying some things? Is this mandated by some standard? Why not always start with the initial bit set, i.e., with `0x8/0x9/.../0xf` and adjust the exponent by -3? That way the representation will be shorter in some cases.

Source code research: [glibc just prints '1' in printf_fphex#285](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/printf_fphex.c.html#285), [newlib just prints '1' in cfprintf#L1746](https://github.com/bminor/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdio/vfprintf.c#L1746) and [musl does `frexpl()*2` in fmt_fp#L210 before converting to digits](https://github.com/ifduyue/musl/blob/master/src/stdio/vfprintf.c#L210). Is there any reason the initial `0x1` is so important that implementations specifically want to print an initial `1`? (And on a side note, why does glibc with `long double` not do it?)

@edit Added `1/3.0L`. And here's a small side-by-side comparison of `long double`s:

```
v>      123.456L                 456.789L                 123.678e10L       678.890e-10L              1/0.3L                   0.5L
GLIBC   0xf.6e978d4fdf3b646p+3   0xe.464fdf3b645a1cbp+5   0x8.ffaea918p+37  0x9.1ca5f58d208ac05p-27   0xd.555555555555555p-2   0x8p-4
MUSL    0x1.edd2f1a9fbe76c8cp+6  0x1.c8c9fbe76c8b4396p+8  0x1.1ff5d523p+40  0x1.2394beb1a411580ap-24  0x1.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaap+1  0x1p-1
NEWLIB  0x1.edd2f1a9fbe77p+6     0x1.c8c9fbe76c8b4p+8     0x1.1ff5d523p+40  0x1.2394beb1a4116p-24     0x1.aaaaaaaaaaaabp+1     0x1p-1
```

Comment: The standard says `where there is one hexadecimal digit (which is nonzero if the argument is a normalized floating-point number and is otherwise unspecified) before the decimal-point character` and `1` is the common nonzero digit (or even integer constant) in C.

Comment: Sure, that's from C standard. But I thought: maybe some other standard requires to print initial 1? An open question.

Comment: KamilCuk, please re-run with `L` append to constants.  Also recommend another "nice" value like `1/3.0L`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This most likely because most implementations use IEEE754 representation for floating point numbers.

This representation store a number of precision bits explicitly (23 for single, 52 for double), but also a single implicit bit which is always 1.  So by always printing the value 1 to the left of the radix point, the values to the right correspond exactly to the precision part of the representation.  This allows for easier debugging of values stored in this format.

Comment: The implicit bit is not always one, and Apple’s implementation starts with “1.” even when the implicit bit is zero.

Answer (score 1):

> Why printf implementators prefer to print %a number with leading 1?

First, all implementations meets the C spec<sup>*</sup>.

> ... A double argument representing a floating-point number is converted in the style
> [-]0xh.hhhhp+-d, where there is one hexadecimal digit (which is nonzero if the argument is a normalized floating-point number and is otherwise unspecified) before the decimal-point character and the number of hexadecimal digits after it is equal to the precision;
> if the precision is missing and `FLT_RADIX` is a power of 2, then the precision is sufficient for an exact representation of the value; ... C17 § 7.21.6.1 8

---

Using `double` constants obscures the test.  Better to append a `L` to the constants: (`123.456` --> `123.456L`).  As is, with `long double nums[]`, all the values have trailing zeros precision bits when saved as `long double` and `"%La"` lops trailing significant `'0'` in printing.

Note in the `long double 1.234560e+02` case, `0xf.6e978d4fdf3b8p+3` and `0x1.edd2f1a9fbe77p+6` are both 53 significant digits.

The rational I see implementations use `1` or `1 to F` to accomplish **1 of 2 goals**:

- Always lead with 1 for a non-zero finite value.  If the FP significand has other than 4*n+1 digits, the n<sup>th</sup> hex digit will not use all 16 choices.  (I'll call this left justified.)
- Lead with [1 to F or less] for a non-zero finite value such that a full precision output (e.g. 64 bits for select [long double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format)) could use all 16 choices in the least significant hex digit.  (I'll call this right justified.)

In the case of GLIBC `long double`, (assuming 10-bit extended FP) had the value had some non-zero trailing precision bits  (use `L`), I'd expect it would have printed 16 hex digits for the significant whereas the others would have used 17 hex digits.

I see a preference to the first one "use a `1`" as it is simpler to explain: "Always lead with 1 for a non-zero finite value."

---

<sup>*</sup>, **except** maybe `long double` fails to print with sufficient precision in *at least* the `NEWLIB` case (per my testing using `L`).  I'll research this more.

Comment: `Using double constants obscures the test.` my thought was, that it doesn't, the numbers do not matter, as long as they are not subnormal, it will always print initial `0x1`. I see no difference with numbers with `L` suffix or not. I think you are right, the precision in newlib is wrong, printing `0x9.999999999999999p-5L` and `0x9.99999999999999ap-5L` and `0x9.99999999999999bp-5L` all result in `0x1.3333333333333p-2` in newlib. (I think that the distributed newlib is compiled without LONGDBL support and casts long double to double)

Comment: @KamilCuk "I see no difference with numbers with L suffix or not" --> Was the `long double` output is all 3 cases the same?  The maximum length of output is a hint as to "why" the lead digit might not be `1`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I suspect you are correct about newlib and " casts long double to double".